# Unarmed strikes with Monk/Aarakocra

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, monk, unarmed-combat, aarakocra

I am playing a Level 5 Monk/Aarakocra with the monk I get 1d6 + 5 (20 dex) but with Aarakocra’s talons I get 1d4 + 5. Does it become 1d6 + 1d4 + 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The Aarakocra racial trait *Talons* states:

> You are proficient with your unarmed strikes, which deal 1d4 slashing damage on a hit.

Compare this to the monk’s *Martial Arts* feature:

> You ***can*** roll a d4 ***in place of*** the normal damage of your unarmed strike or monk weapon. This die changes as you gain levels.... *(emphasis my own*

This indicates the Martial Arts die replaces your default Aarakocra unarmed strike die of 1d4, and is not an addition to it. You can also choose to roll just the d4, although that’s probably less likely to be done.

Your damage roll, at level 5, is one of the following as you choose it to be:

- 1d6 + 5 slashing
- 1d4 + 5 slashing